# View how HTML appeared in the past?

Tags: html, selenium, scrapy

Is there a tool or service I can use to identify how a website looked liked a year ago if they have access to the website's html code? For instance, say I save how nba.com's html code today, can I see how this html code visually appeared today, in a year's time?

I'm asking because instead of scraping websites daily to obtain info and manually checking if the info is in the same position, what's stopping me from scraping a website's html code and retroactively looking back at the script and accessing the information I need?

Answer (score 1):

This site has a history of what web pages looked like in olden times...

https://archive.org/web/

And they do provide an API:

https://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php

Comment: I know that, but if I have the historic html code of a website, is there a tool I can use to graphically view how it looked historically?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but a web browser can open html files that you have saved locally to the filesystem. You just need to have all the files laid out in the same structure